# DISTINCT query not returning value 1

Tags: php, distinct

I have this query returning rows from table but it returns all values other than 1.

The output is for example : 2, 3, 5, 20, 22 etc but the id output 1 is never there but i am expecting it to be.

I do not understand why?

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(driver_profileId) FROM driver_profiles";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if ($row) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['driver_profileId'] . '<br />';
   }
}
else {
      echo "noRow"; 
}
```

Comment: I think that is because you are using `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` twice. You don't need to do that.

Comment: If I daresay, you in fact need to don't do that. Once you fetched it once, it's fetched. If you fetch again, you overwrite the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(driver_profileId) FROM driver_profiles";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)or die(mysqli_error($conn));

if ($result ) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      echo $row['driver_profileId'] . '<br />';
   }
}
else {
  echo "noRow"; 
}
```

You're using `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`twice.

Comment: That's done it! i knew something wasn't quite right but couldn't quite figure it out! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think 1st call to `mysqli_fetch_array` move record pointer to 1st record. Then you are again calling in while condition again `mysqli_fetch_array`. So you are always starting from the 2nd record skipping the 1st one.